# Using libsass with Rails asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass, libsass

I'm trying to get libsass to work with the Rails 4 asset pipeline. So far I've cloned the [ruby-libsass](https://github.com/sass/ruby-libsass) Gem from Github into the Vendor folder of my application. I added the followig to my gemfile:

```
gem 'sassc', path: 'vendor/ruby-libsass/'
```

I then followed the docs and added the submodules for libsass. Within the libsass folder I had to clone in the [sass2scss](https://github.com/mgreter/sass2scss) library for it to compile. I compiled it with `make install-shared` which created `/usr/local/lib/libsass.so`. After this, running `rake assets:precompile` give the following error:

```
rake aborted!
LoadError: Could not open library 'sass': dlopen(sass, 5): image not found.
Could not open library 'libsass.dylib': dlopen(libsass.dylib, 5): image not found
```

So I symlinked `libsass.dylib` this to `/usr/local/lib/libsass.dylib`. After that, I received the following error:

`NameError: uninitialized constant SassC::Lib::Context::SassOptions`

I tried commenting out the line in `/ruby-libsass/lib/sassc/lib/context.rb` that calls SassOptions, and that seemed to have made it work and compiling the assets. The commented out code on line 20, context.rb:

```
layout :source_string, :pointer,
  :output_string, :string,
  # :options, SassOptions,
  :error_status, :int,
  :error_message, :string,
  :c_functions, :pointer,
  :included_files, :pointer,
  :num_included_files, :int`
```

Now, the problem I'm having is that I see no speed difference. It stays at around 7 seconds to compile my assets, with or without adding libsass to my Gemfile. Since the initial compile gave an error relating tot libsass.dylib file not being found, I assumed that it's actually using sassc instead of sass, but it looks like it isn't.

Any ideas what I could be missing? I have no experience with C, so I'm not even sure if I compiled everything correctly, etc.

Comment: this guy had it working in the past, it looks like he had to fork sass-rails: https://github.com/andrew/libsass-rails

Comment: in `context.rb`, add the following to the top: `require_relative 'sass_options'`.

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a go when I have a minute and see if that makes any difference. I think the problem is more that the compiled libraries don't get used.

Comment: Don't know yet. Involved with a startup and don't have a whole lot of time to play around with stuff at the moment. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, I finally got it working thanks to [this gem](https://github.com/bolandrm/sassc-rails)! The project is still a WIP, and can do with a few supporters. :)

Only issue I ran into is that you need to completely remove `sass-rails` from your project, which can be a problem if you use gems like ActiveAdmin. There are workarounds though. Then, plain css files that get included in your scss files with `@import` need to have `.css` at the end of the filename in the import.